# I am not able to login to a website using Python and the Requests library. What am I missing?

Tags: python, python-requests

My project is retrieve information from a website. After finding that the only browser I can use is firefox 47 and that Selenium doesn't support this version, I decided to try to do it with the Requests library and BeautifulSoup.

The first step is to login to the website, and I can't make it work using Requests.

Here is what I tried:

- Using the firefox web development tool, I have retrieved information about the headers, cookie and data which I used to create a session.

```
import requests


login_url = "https://ip.adress/website/session/login.php"
protected_url = "https://ip.adress/website/#dashboard/overview/overview"


cookies = {
    'sess': '4rk02yn7r1l3pn0bkj4zk',
    'PHPSESSID': 'ogtkif390qrhur8b3krm4anf53',
}

headers = {
    'Host': 'ip.adress',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Referer': 'https://ip.adress/website/session/login.php',
    # 'Cookie': 'sess=4rk02yn7r1l3pn0bkj4zk; PHPSESSID=ogtkif390qrhur8b3krm4anf53',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
}

data = {
    'embed': '',
    'bookmark_string': '',
    'user': 'username',
    'passu': 'password',
    'pass': 'random string which depends on the passu value',
}


with requests.Session() as s:
    r1 = s.get(login_url, verify=False)
    r2 = s.post(login_url, cookies=cookies, headers=headers, data=data, verify=False)
    r3 = s.get(protected_url, verify=False)

    print(r3.text)
```

Unfortunately, `print(r3.text)` gives me the html of the login page.

Also `print(r3.history)` gives me Response 302.

Here is what the form in the login page looks like if it helps:

```
<form name="f_login" id="f_login" method="POST" action="login.php">
                    <input type="hidden" name="embed" value=""/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="bookmark_string" id="bookmark_string" value=''/>
....
....
<input type="text" size='25' maxlength="64" id='user' name="user" value="" />

                                                        <input type="password" onfocus="$('#wup').hide(); $('#nt_1').hide(); $('#nt_pass').hide();" id="passu" size='25' name="passu" autocomplete="off"/>
                                                        <input type="hidden" id="pass" name="pass"/>
```

Edit:
r2 headers look like this:

````
`header_2 = {'Date': 'Mon, 19 Dec 2022 16:09:58 GMT', 'Server': 'Apache',
            'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
            'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload',
            'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block',
            'Vary': 'User-Agent,Accept-Encoding',
            'Expires': 'Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate',
            'Pragma': 'no-cache',
            'Content-Encoding': 'gzip',
            'Content-Length': '2946', 'Keep-Alive': 'timeout=5, max=97',
            'Connection': 'Keep-Alive',
            'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
            }```
````

Comment: is the website also making a request to a backend service?

Comment: What kind of authentication does the site use?

I assume it's some kind of token authentication, where they give you the bearer token in the response headers of your login request (`r2.headers` in your case). 

If that is the case, you need to add that token to the headers of your next request (`r3`).

Comment: @se7en I don't know, Is there is a way I can check that using a browser ?

Comment: @JovanV I don't know yet, how can I find the kind of authentication ?

Comment: Well, for starters you can debug `r2`. See if `r2` is a 200 response. Then see its headers. Does it have `cookies` or `Authentication` header, or neither of those?

Of course, if the website of interest has documentation on this topic, read that first.

Comment: @JovanV, r2 is a 200 response, i have edited my main post with r2 headers.

Comment: You can't reuse an old cookie.  You have to fetch the login page, and use the cookie it returns to you to send the login information.  The requests Session should be tracking the cookies for you.